# Cross-reference to the next section, whatever it is

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering

Some sections of my document start with a remark such as the following: "This section may be omitted at the first reading."

I'd like to add to this text a (hypertext) reference to the next section (page) number and I can do it by labeling the next section (`\label{sec:next}`) and make use of `\ref{sec:next}` and/or `\pageref{sec:next}`. But, because the `sec:next` label is hard coded, the reference could be wrong in case of changes in the order of the sections.

Hence my question: is there a way to refer to the next section, whatever it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have to setup a `\label` that will be evaluated at the next `\section` command.

So I patch `\@sect` to add a `\label` command to its argument `#8` (which refers to the main section title), which is evaluated only if the command has been called by `\section` and a `\nextsection` command has been issued. Also `\section` and `\subsection` need to be patched, because they both use `\@sect` for typesetting the title. The argument to `\label` is automatically generated via a counter.

Note that the patches must be made before `hyperref` is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@nextsection
\newif\if@section
\newcounter{ns@count}
\newcommand{\nextsection}{%
  \global\@nextsectiontrue
  \stepcounter{ns@count}%
  \xdef\@nstemp{ns@@\thens@count}%
  \ref{ns@@\@nstemp}%
}

\patchcmd{\@sect}
  {#8}
  {#8%
   \if@section\if@nextsection
     \label{ns@@\@nstemp}\global\@nextsectionfalse
   \fi\fi}
  {}{}
\preto\section{\global\@sectiontrue}
\preto\subsection{\global\@sectionfalse}
\makeatother

%%% hyperref should go after the patch, if used
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\section{TL;DR}

This section is long, go to section~\nextsection.

\subsection{A}

\newpage

\section{THIS IS IT}\label{foo}

\newpage

\section{Again TL;DR}
Check if it works \ref{foo}; now go to section~\nextsection.

\newpage

\section{Another}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly well. Would this be easily extended to other sectioning levels, as parts or chapters?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The idea would be the same; but the more patches you do, the more fragile the entire building becomes.

Answer (score 3):

This answer has been EDITED to work for the next section, the next subsection, as well as the next subsubsection.

In essence, rather that try to invoke a label in one place meant to apply to a subsequent report section, it makes more sense to me to create macros `\nextsection`, `\nextsubsection`, and `\nextsubsubsection` in which the next [[sub]sub]section number is computed based on the current [[sub]sub]section number.  It will, however, require you to know in advance whether the next sectioning unit entity is a section, a subsection, or a subsubsection.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{nextsec}
\newcommand\nextsection{%
  \setcounter{nextsec}{\thesection}%
  \stepcounter{nextsec}%
  \thenextsec%
}
\newcommand\nextsubsection{%
  \setcounter{nextsec}{\expandafter\parsesub\thesubsection\relax}%
  \stepcounter{nextsec}%
  \thesection.\thenextsec%
}
\newcommand\nextsubsubsection{%
  \edef\tmp{\thesubsubsection}%
  \setcounter{nextsec}{\expandafter\parsesubsub\tmp\relax}%
  \stepcounter{nextsec}%
  \thesubsection.\thenextsec%
}
\def\parsesub#1.#2\relax{#2}
\def\parsesubsub#1.#2.#3\relax{#3}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section\label{s:first}}

This is section \ref{s:first}.  The following section is \nextsection,\\
but the next subsection is \nextsubsection.

\subsection{A subsection\label{s:firstsub}}

This is subsection \ref{s:firstsub}.  The following subsection is \nextsubsection.

\subsection{Next subsection}

\section{Next Section}

The next subsubsection will be \nextsubsubsection.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful but I should have mentioned (should I edit the original question?) that I'd like to refer to the page of the section as well and, on top of that ;), I'd like to make the text an hyperlink to the next section.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé  I do see in your original question the phrase `\(page)ref{sec:next}`.  That, of course, is not the right syntax for getting a page number, but I see now that you had mentioned the word "page" in your question.  So perhaps, an edit is a viable course of action, for clarification.